# Multiple S3 buckets in the same CloudFront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I created a Cloudfront distribution with a CNAME `images.domain.com` with SSL, and I have 2 S3 buckets: one for user uploads, one for product pictures

The default bucket is the uploads bucket

I would like to use the same CloudFront for both buckets.

So I added the 2 buckets as origins and created a "Behavior", with the path `/products/*` using my product bucket as origin

My "Behaviors" are :

1. /products/* to: products bucket (precedence = 0)
2. Default (*) to: uploads bucket (precedence = 1)

When I go to `images.domain.com/products/78/34.jpg` I get an AccessDenied

The file "78/34.jpg" is present in my products bucket

Files from the other bucket are working fine (ie `images.domain.com/upload67.jpg` with upload67.jpg in the uploads bucket)

Answer (score 13):

The pattern `/products/*` matches all objects in the specified origin bucket that are in a folder called 'products'. So, the key needs to be `products/78/34.jpg`.

If you create a folder called 'products' inside the products bucket and move the 73/34.jpg file in to it, the `images.domain.com/products/78/34.jpg` url should then work (you might need to invalidate if you recently got a error before creating the folder).

Comment: I also found this forum post when double checking my answer: 

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=550914

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add access public policy to your products bucket

```
{
  "Version":"2008-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
         },
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Make sure you replace bucket in arn:aws:s3:::bucket/* with your bucket name.

Comment: already tried on both buckets, always AccessDenied on the "product" one, the other is fine. When I create an other cloudfront with the "product" bucket as the default, it's working, but I want one cloudfront for both if possible