# Access multiple S3 buckets at root path as origins in CloudFront distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have setup a CloudFront distribution with two S3 buckets.

When setting up the distribution I set it up with `bukect1`. Then added another origin for `bucket2`.

I then created a new behavior to target `bucket2`. For the Path Pattern I've put `cf/*`.

So then I would try to get files from `bucket2` by hitting:

`<Id>.cloudfront.net/cf/example.pdf`

I kept getting **access denied**.

So after looking around for a while I found this:

[Multiple S3 buckets in the same CloudFront distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30197296/multiple-s3-buckets-in-the-same-cloudfront-distribution)

That allowed me to understand that hitting:

`<Id>.cloudfront.net/cf/example.pdf`

would cause cloudfront to indeed look in `bucket2`, but, within the `cf` directory.

So then I moved `example.pdf` in a directory called `cf` and things worked.

QUESTION:

Is it possible to access files **at the root level of bucket2** via cloudfront when using multiple origins specifying Path Patterns in behaviors? Is the only way to work with multiple origins to have things not at the root level in the buckets I want to access?

I am able to access the files at root level in `bucket1`, that is the first bucket I have specified when creating the distribution. Other than `bucket1`, I cannot access fils at buckets root level.

Any idea?

Comment: Some answers mentioned lambda@edge here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446228/hosting-multiple-s3-origins-under-one-cloudfront-distribution I never done it before though.

Comment: that seems a good option. Not sure how to implement it and prove that it does that job yet, but, I'll check it out.