# Mapping multiple S3 buckets to the same URL using AWS CloudFront - Access Denied error on non-default path patterns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, amazon-cloudfront

How can I map two different S3 buckets to the same URL using AWS CloudFront?

I have created two origins; one origin with path /preview of one bucket and another with the path /harry for another bucket. In the behaviors section, I have set the Default behavior to use the /preview origin and a separate behavior with the /harry/* path pattern that uses the /epub origin. However, only the Default behavior is working and the /harry/* pattern returns an "Access Denied" error.

URL example:

- https://xxxx.cloudfront.net/harry/example.xhtml  =  Access Denied
- https://xxxx.cloudfront.net/image.png  =  Works fine

Cloud front configuration:

- Origins: https://postimg.cc/N9MQh5dQ
- Behaviors: https://postimg.cc/KkKCrL93

Preview Origin policy

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E3HIYxxxx"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxstorage/preview/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

harry origin policy

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E3HIYxxxx"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxdevelopment/harry/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The issue with this configuration is that only the Default behavior is working, regardless of the associated origin. Is there something that I am missing or not properly configured in this setup?

Answer (score 0):

I aim to do the same thing that you are trying to do, but am still in the research phase.

It seems you need a folder inside the alternative bucket with a name which matches the trailing portion of the bucket Origin Domain Name.

There is an brief post on this topic from 2015:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32002341

As well as an excellent blog post and YouTube video:  https://vimalpaliwal.com/blog/2018/10/10f435c29f/serving-multiple-s3-buckets-via-single-aws-cloudfront-distribution.html

This is the approach that I will take as I move forward.